# Enable minor-mode during function call

Tags: minor-mode

Similar to the somewhat neat, but in the end too clunky, `hydra-goto-line`, I'd like to customize `goto-line` to enable linum-mode, but only during the function call.

I tried `add-advice`, `:before` and `:after`, but nothing kinda happened. So what's the proper way to enable a minor-mode during a single function call?

Comment: Please elaborate on *exactly* what it is that you are trying to achieve. Something which is enabled "only during the function call" is rather unlikely to ever get a chance to affect the display.

Comment: And show the code you tried, for which you say only "nothing kinda happened." Not much to go on, here. You might help yourself by helping others help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably borrowed this from *somewhere*, but darned if I remember where:

```
(defun goto-line-with-feedback ()
  "Show line numbers temporarily, while prompting for the line number input."
  (interactive)
  (defvar goto/line 0)
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (linum-mode 1)
        (setq goto/line (read-number "Goto line: "))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (forward-line (1- goto/line)))
    (linum-mode -1)))
```

I rebind `M-g` to that; works a treat.

(Note that if you're using Emacs 26, you should use `display-line-numbers-mode` instead of `linum-mode` -- just swapping the two function calls is all you need to do.)

As a *general* rule — to try to address your question in a more generic, "teach you to fish" kind of way — any function of the form `foo-mode` in Emacs will take a positive argument to unconditionally enable the mode, and a negative (or sometimes `nil`) argument to unconditionally disable it. The best way to validate that is to read the documentation for the function (`C-h f` then the function name).